# meteor write file on meteor.com

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, fs

I want to deploy a meteor app to meteor.com.

Unfortunately I have to write some tmp files to the public folder of meteor.

Example Code:

```
var fs = Npm.require('fs');
var filepath = "../../../../../public/resizing/tmp~";
fs.open(localpath, 'w', function(err,fd)
{
   if(err) throw "error opening file";
   fs.close(fd,function(){});
}
```

( `../../../../../public` is the location of the meteor public folder after bundling! )

This works fine on my local machine, because I have write privileges inside the public folder. Is there a way how I can write to a tmp file in an app that is deployed to meteor?

Comment: Can you tell a little more about what you are going to do with this file, because maybe there is some workaround solution which does not require writing to a file in the local file system.

Comment: I want to resize the images using imagemagick and then uplaod them to s3. The problem with buffering the images in memory was the other option, but there seems to be a problem storing binary data in a js variable? (for some images the app crashed)

Comment: If this is the case then use `filepicker.io`. It does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most cloud providers don't allow access to file system, because this would put too much constraints on the architecture. Meteor.com is not different. <s>For Meteor, there's also a problem of `/public` dir being precached by the engine, so every change to that folder would result in server being restarted (you can see that on your local machine as well).</s>

Whatever you're trying to achieve, there are different ways. The most common ones are:

- Use an external storage system, such as Amazon S3.
- Simply, write the files you need as a new collection in the database. It's obvious how to do it for text files, but as easy for binary ones - just convert them to base64.

Comment: the point about the server restarting is actually not true, since i put an '~' at the end of the file name

Comment: Right, I forgot about the ~.

Answer (score 1):

Meteor allows people to deploy apps to meteor.com as a courtesy, but I agree that writing to the file system dynamically would be a security risk for them. You can package your app and deploy it to your own server somewhere if that's easier, but you might want to rewrite the app logic itself to keep that data somewhere other than the same location of your app (S3, for instance). I'm assuming you're trying to store images or something. If it's not, just use Meteor's data stores and keep it there.

Comment: Yes, I save the images to S3, but I store them for a short time while resizing them on the server.