# Imagemagick integrated with Meteor

Tags: imagemagick, meteor

I am attempting to use Imagemagick to manipulate images that are uploaded by a user. Right now I have a simple set of Imagemagick.convert[ ] commands server side that preform a variety of tasks on the uploaded image. My problem comes from Imagemagick needing the file data to be read into meteor and not from a url. What I end up doing is writing the uploaded file to the /public folder where Imagemagick is able to manipulate the image. However because the list of Imagemagick.convert commands (saving and writing to /public), the application keeps refreshing, breaking up the processes and sending it into an infinite refreshing cycle. I don't think assets is a viable solution, but I need some folder that I can write to in meteor that will not interrupt the various Imagemagick processes through a refresh. I have tried the .folder for a hidden folder, but meteor gives me an error: "You can’t use a name that begins with a dot “.”, because these names are reserved for the system. Please choose another name." Any thoughts?

Comment: This [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961296/meteor-write-file-on-meteor-com) says that adding `~` to the end of the file name will prevent restarts for file changes.

Comment: You should not manipulate your files in `public` dir. Use your system `tmp` instead and only write to `public` the final result.

Comment: I have also tried using the '~' at the end. What would the path be to write to 'tmp' from my meteor server?

Comment: I added a tmp~ folder to my server file in meteor. It works great, but is it good practice to have such a folder?

Answer (score 0):

@Nate I wrote a little example app that solves this problem by using a **temporary directory** (as others have suggested):

**https://github.com/ideaq/image-uploads**

My solution gives you:

- *Easy* **image uploading** in any **Meteor** app
- Images are re-sized to **Thumbnail**, **Mobile Optimised** and Full-size Original
- Images are uploaded to **AWS S3** for **CDN** delivery (scalability and speed)
- A **thumbnail** of the image is displayed on to the user *without refreshing the page*

[image: Demo of the upload functionality]

if you found a better way of doing image uploads in meteor, please share! thanks. :-)

Comment: I like it! I am using imagemagick to perform unique manipulations that cannot be done via normal js. But for storing files I would recommend collectionFS. It is built off of mongo's gridFS and uses a meteor Collection scheme. Implementation is easy and fast. Check it out (https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS)

Comment: I had a look at collectionFS. Considering that storage space for most MongoDB hosting providers is *extortionate*, storing images in Mongo is not very economical. https://www.mongohq.com/pricing So S3 is the way to go for large volumes of data. and simply store the S3 url in DB.

Comment: That is very true and something to defiantly keep in mind. I will check out S3. It sounds like a good thing to pursue.